# how to set config before import in pytest conftest.py?

Tags: python, config, tox

I have `myprj` project, and files are as below.

```
$ tree myprj/
myprj/
├── prj
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── my_logger.py
│   ├── my_module.py
│   └── tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── conftest.py
│       └── unit
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── test_my_module.py
├── setup.py
└── tox.ini
```

**config.py**

```
LOG_FILE='/path/exists/on/production/prj.log'
```

**my_logger.py**

```
from prj import config
import logging

class MyLogger():
    def __init__(self):
        self.setup_logger()

    def setup_logger(self):
        logFilename = config.LOG_FILE

        file_hdlr = logging.FileHandler(logFilename)
```

**my_module.py**

```
from prj import my_logger

myLogger = my_logger.MyLogger()


def my_method():
    return 1
```

**test_my_module.py**

```
from prj import my_module

def test_my_method():
    assert 1 == my_module.my_method()
```

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="Tox Testing")
```

**tox.ini**

```
[tox]
envlist = py35

[testenv]
deps=pytest
commands=py.test
```

When I run `tox` it fails with `path not exists` for log file.

```
GLOB sdist-make: /private/tmp/myprj/setup.py
py35 inst-nodeps: /private/tmp/myprj/.tox/dist/Tox Testing-0.0.0.zip
py35 installed: attrs==17.4.0,pluggy==0.6.0,py==1.5.2,pytest==3.3.2,six==1.11.0,Tox-Testing==0.0.0
py35 runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='2231398989'
py35 runtests: commands[0] | py.test
========================================================================================================= test session starts =========================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.3.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /private/tmp/myprj, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors

=============================================================================================================== ERRORS ================================================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting prj/tests/unit/test_my_module.py __________________________________________________________________________________________
prj/tests/unit/test_my_module.py:1: in <module>
    from prj import my_module
prj/my_module.py:3: in <module>
    myLogger = my_logger.MyLogger()
prj/my_logger.py:6: in __init__
    self.setup_logger()
prj/my_logger.py:11: in setup_logger
    file_hdlr = logging.FileHandler(logFilename)
/Users/nile2691/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py:1008: in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
/Users/nile2691/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py:1037: in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
E   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/exists/on/production/prj.log'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
======================================================================================================= 1 error in 0.36 seconds =======================================================================================================
ERROR: InvocationError: '/private/tmp/myprj/.tox/py35/bin/py.test'
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________ summary _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
ERROR:   py35: commands failed
```

I get that, log file path is not exists in my local system, and it gives error.

I tried to set the `LOG_FILE` variable in `config.py` using `conftest.py` fixture.

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest
from prj import config


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def set_config():
    config.LOG_FILE = '/tmp/prj.log'
```

But still it return same error. If I am able to invoke something before start the test execution, like, `py.test`'s first execution step, then I can set the `LOG_FILE` and it would not raise error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the global scope of `my_module.py`, you create an instance `my_logger.MyLogger()` and in `MyLogger.__init__` logging handlers are set up.

**Your problem is the anti-pattern of setting up logging handlers at import time**.  Don't do that.

For apps, logging handlers should be configured at runtime (done by `main()` or whatever).  For libraries, logging handlers should not be configured at all (with the exception of [possibly adding a `NullHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library)) - it is up to the user of your library to decide how they want handlers configured.

Note that pytest does not require that logging handlers are already configured in order to test the records logged and make assertions about log events - the `caplog` fixture will insert its own handlers in order to capture the logging events, so it can be used even with an unconfigured logging system.

Comment: Thanks wim, I get it at first time, that setting `MyLogger` is issue, but I cant change it easily, I have plan to change that, but before that, I have make my test running. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: No, there is no good way to do it, because the damage has already been done by the time your code is imported (the line `from prj import config` in `conftest.py` has configured already, so it's too late for the `set_config` fixture to change anything).  It's necessary to refactor how you setup the logging.

Comment: Not sure whether this is _good_ practice but it would be possible to import the module `my_module` in `test_my_module.py` inside the test function `test_my_method()`, so it would be possible to setup the config before the import and usage. But I think subsequent test functions might reuse the globally cached config and logger modules, so it would falsify other tests depending on what they do. I'm not sure whether test functions can discard state to start fresh? Extracting the logging setup would probably be the best and correct way to do it.